# Como puedo hacer recorrer todo un Json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Buenos dias como va?

EL dia de hoy vengo con este problema:

Estoy intentando recorre todo  un array para obtener el datos "Summary" de todos los objectos, este mi array

```js
let data = [
  {
    'Western Sahara': {
      Summary: {
        Country_Region: 'Western Sahara',
        Last_Update: 1591875567445,
        Confirmed: 9,
        Deaths: 1,
        Recovered: 6,
        Active: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    Yemen: {
      Summary: {
        Country_Region: 'Yemen',
        Last_Update: 1591875567446,
        Confirmed: 560,
        Deaths: 129,
        Recovered: 23,
        Active: 408,
      },
    },
  },
];
```

mis intentos de soluciones fueron estas

```js
const keysDatos = Object.keys(data);
console.log(
  'total_cases',
  keysDatos.map((i) => data[i]['Summary'])
);
```

Y me arroja como resultado:

```
total_cases [ undefined, undefined ]
```

Mis intenciones es que se tenga como resultado de todos los Summary, seria como  esto:

```js
 data: [
  {
    Country_Region: 'Western Sahara',
    Last_Update: 1591875567445,
    Confirmed: 9,
    Deaths: 1,
    Recovered: 6,
    Active: 2,
  },
  {
    Country_Region: 'Yemen',
    Last_Update: 1591875567446,
    Confirmed: 560,
    Deaths: 129,
    Recovered: 23,
    Active: 408,
  },
];
```

Comment: ¿Por qué accedes a la propiedad `Confirmed` cuando haces el `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastaría con un map, el cual te recorre cada objeto y generas un objeto nuevo.

Tendrías que buscar el valor de la primer clave dentro de cada objeto del Array y después acceder por índice usando ese valor, asumiendo que siempre la primer propiedad tendrá dentro otra propiedad llamada Summary.

```
data.map(d=>d[Object.keys(d)[0]].Summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cada elemento del array recoge la propiedad summary:

```js
let data = [{
        'Western Sahara': {
            Summary: {
                Country_Region: 'Western Sahara',
                Last_Update: 1591875567445,
                Confirmed: 9,
                Deaths: 1,
                Recovered: 6,
                Active: 2,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        Yemen: {
            Summary: {
                Country_Region: 'Yemen',
                Last_Update: 1591875567446,
                Confirmed: 560,
                Deaths: 129,
                Recovered: 23,
                Active: 408,
            },
        },
    },
];

for (var index in data) {
    for (var name in data[index]) {
        console.log(data[index][name].Summary);
    }

}
```